# Get the contents of a PHP file into a variable for displaying

Tags: php

How can I get the contents of a PHP file (which also contains HTML) into a variable, and then echo them at a later time inside another PHP file? I also need the contents to execute the PHP in it properly. I tried something like the following, but its just giving me a string of all the contents on the page.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("myfile");
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) and [include](http://php.net/include) the file.

```
ob_start();
include( 'myfile');
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Then, at a later time:

```
echo $contents;
```

Comment: I saw this option somewhere else also. Is this okay practice?

Comment: In my opinion it's the best way to capture the output of `myfile` while allowing the PHP code contained within the file to be executed.

Comment: @metro: Generally speaking, yes. Its essentially the basis of template systems that use native php based templates.

Answer (score 0):

One PHP script executing another and capturing its output usually means you are going about things the *wrong way*. If you must, have a look at output buffering, `eval`, and maybe even stuff like `system_exec`.

If you want to solve your problem better you may want to look at a project like CodeIgniter and how its templating system works, especially how small template partials/fragments are rendered and incorporated into larger views/templates.